# How do i change the html source code (CTRL + U) with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to encode some content with base64 and it works, encodes the content in the debugger HTML inspector

BUT if a view the source code pressing `ctrl + u` they can see the original content decrypted (original without encryption), so my question is if there is a way to change or modify the page HTML source with JavaScript or jQuery. I'm not using PHP so its much harder to do :/

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you talking about `injecting` jQuery code in to someone else's website? Because you do realise you'd only be `encoding` it for you and not anyone else.

Comment: Anything that's done with Javascript will done after the page has loaded, so there's not really much point. Someone could just disable Javascript. Also, base64 is not a method of encryption, it's a method of encoding which is a very different thing. It's trivial to decode.

Comment: @Ismael Gonzales, Do you want to protect your browser rendered HTML source with encryption?

Comment: @KrishR yes or something like that, i've seen a site where if you press ctrl + u the site ask for a password (set in a variable with JavaScript) or any other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. you have to consider about using server side language like PHP you mentioned.

Javascript is a client side language which means whole code runs on the client browser. As Javascript can be easily disabled, plain text can show up to the user.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought, so the answer would be. no, at least with JavaScript thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are asking, so let me answer based on what I think you are asking. I think you are asking: "Can javascript inject content into the web page?".

You can edit the DOM with javascript (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp)
The easiest way is to have a tag that you want the content go in:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Then write some javascript to put data into that tag

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += 'The thing you want to put on the page';
```

Edit:
The javascript is client side so they will be able to find the javascript file. If you don't want them to be able to see the original code / content at all then it has to be done server-side. What are you using instead? Most web server applications have templating available which might do what you want.